# Convert string to int using char array

Tags: java, string, loops, int, sum

how can I create a loop that also turns string "abcc" into the sum of their letter position, say a=1 b=2 c=3 and it sums the string 1+2+3+3=9.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Test
    {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
            String original = "hello";
            char[] chars = original.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(chars);
            String sorted = new String(chars);
            System.out.println(sorted);


                }
           }
```

Comment: The ASCII for a = 97, b = 98 etc. You could loop through the numbers and subtract 96 to get 1, 2 etc.

Comment: Do you know that characters can be cast to integers or be added and subtracted? `int number = 'c'-'a';//=2`.

Comment: Thank you guys. I like to use java  occasionally, but my knowledge gets so rusty after a year :(.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values. `a` has value `97`, `b` has `98` and so on.

```
private int printSum(String original){
    int sum = 0;
    if(original!=null){
        char[] arr = original.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for(int x :arr){
            sum+= (x-96);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This only works with lowercase letters. Uppercase would mean subtracting 65.

Comment: @rethab I know that , that is why I linked the ASCII table with my answer .

Comment: You could solve that by simply calling toLowerCase() before toCharArray()

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the fact that characters can be cast to an Integer, and thereby take on their ASCII value. e.g. System.out.println((int)'a') would print '97'. Knowing that, you only have to subtract a certain number based on whether it's an upper- or lowercase letter and you get 1 for a, 2 for b etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove non-alphabet characters from the string using regular expressions
2. Modify string with toLower() or toUpper()
3. Convert the string into charArray
4. Set initial result as 0
5. Foreach char in the array, subtract the char value with 64 (if you use UPPERCASE) or 96 (if you use lowercase) and add it into result

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions: One with a loop as requested, and one with recursion.
This works with both upper- and lowercase letters, but doesn't take non-alphabetical letters into account. This can easily be tested for in an if-statement, with the following criteria: `Character.isAlphabetic( c )`.

```
public class Main {

    static final int LOWERCASE_OFFSET = 96;
    static final int UPPERCASE_OFFSET = 64;

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println(recursion( "Abcc" ));
    }

    static int recursion( String str ) {
        if( str.isEmpty() )
            return 0;

        char c = str.charAt( 0 );
        int charVal = Character.isUpperCase( c ) ? c - UPPERCASE_OFFSET : c - LOWERCASE_OFFSET;
        return charVal + recursion( str.substring( 1 ) );
    }

    static int loop( String str ) {
        int val = 0;
        for( char c : str.toCharArray() ) {
            val += Character.isUpperCase( c ) ? c - UPPERCASE_OFFSET : c - LOWERCASE_OFFSET;
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```